# Seems like Netty HashedWheelTimer does not work under heavy CPU load

Tags: netty

We have a Netty-based application which stops working under heavy CPU load. I'm pretty sure the reason is HashedWheelTimer skips buckets at 100% CPU usage and never triigers execution of major part of it's tasks.

Such hich loading occurs on our server from time to time and is unpredictable but does not last much time. Anyway this is enough for our customer's devices DDoS our server which does not disconnect unauthorized devices because of HashedWheelTimer failure.

So the question is: am I right? Does HashedWheelTimer really have this issue? We implemented timer class which will trigger all events whouse time has come. And I think there is a need in such class in a standard Netty distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If thats the case then please open a bug in our [issue tracker](https://github.com/netty/netty).